# Detect how long is mouse down

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

Can someone show me how to monitor how long the mouse is down, and on mouse up display that time in seconds?

Comment: note when it was pressed; note when it was released; subtract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdZgGp) where you can time how long a `<button>` element is held down for. This is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<button id="button">click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
    'use strict';
    var start;
    var end;
    var delta;
    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        start = new Date();
    });

    button.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        end = new Date();
        delta = (end - start) / 1000.0;
        alert("Button held for " + delta + " seconds." )
    });
})(window, document);
```

You probably don't want to use an `alert` in your application, but that is a good starting point. You should be able to insert the `delta` value into a DOM element without an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I really needed this.